# Store Selenium HTML Source Code into element of type HTMLDocument

Tags: html, vba, excel, selenium, xhtml

Is it possible to store the HTML source grabbed with Selenium (using Excel VBA) into a `HTMLDocument` element? 
This is an example using `Microsoft Internet Controls` and `Microsoft HTML Object Library` to automate Internet Explorer.

```
Dim IE as InternetExplorer
Dim HTML as HTMLDocument
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
ie.navigate "www.google.com"
set HTML = IE.Document
```

can the same be dome with Selenium? For example something like (not working!):

```
Dim selenium As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Set selenium = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
Dim html as HTMLDocument

selenium.Start "firefox", "about:blank"
selenium.Open "file:///D:/webpages/LE_1001.htm"
Set html = selenium.getHtmlSource 'this is not working since .getHtmlSource() 
                                 'returns a String object but is there a way to store 
                                 'this html source into a type of HTMLDocument-element
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to get the DOM with SeleniumBasic:

```
Sub Get_DOM()
  Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
  driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

  Dim html As New HTMLDocument  ' Requires Microsoft HTML Library
  html.body.innerHTML = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;")

  Debug.Print html.body.innerText

  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above example:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Comment: this is for getting the html body. How can I load the html body to a web page I mean to load the page into selenium driver based on html body?

Comment: Is there a way to get the request headers while using selenium VBA?

Answer (score 2):

This should work to use a string as the source for an HTML document:

```
Set html = New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = selenium.pageSource
```

edit: changed Selenium call to pageSource from getHtmlSource. Full working code as follows. Not sure that we're using the same version of Selenium though:

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()

Dim sel As selenium.WebDriver
Set sel = New selenium.WebDriver
Dim html As HTMLDocument

sel.Start "firefox", "about:blank"
sel.Get "http://www.google.com/"

Set html = New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = sel.PageSource

Debug.Print html.body.innerText

End Sub
```

with references to Microsoft HTML Object Library and Selenium Type Library (Selenium32.tlb) - using SeleniumBasic version 2.0.6.0

Comment: at the line `html.body.innerHTML = selenium.getHtmlSource` I receive a `Run-time error: 438: Object doesn't support this property or method` ... any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've updated my answer - I think the error was from the call to Selenium and not from the HTMLDocument

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. It works with a slight problem, namely the `HTML code` from the original ("google.com") has far more characters than the source code inserted into the `HTMLDocument` object: original has `425.640` and the HTMLDocument object has `7.814`... so not all code is copied. Do you have any ideas on this one? Thank you.

Comment: Are you comparing like-with-like? I used body.innerText in my example just to keep the amount of text printed to a manageable amount. To compare with the length of the original, look at the length of html.body.innerHTML instead. The innerHTML may be a bit shorter than the original document due to the elimination of unnecessary whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you prefer converting an Selenium element to a HTMLDocument. It'd require one more bounded dependency to your project.

Personally I prefer allocating DOM-element to a WebElement. For instance:

```
If (Selenium.FindElementsByClass("qty").Count > 0) Then
    Dim qtyElement as WebElement: Set qtyElement = Selenium.FindElementByClass("qty")
End If

If (Not qtyElement is Nothing) then
    Dim qtyHtml as String: qtyHtml = qrtElement.Attribute("innerHTML")
End if

Debug.Print qtyHtml
```