# Parse local webpages with Selenium in VBA Excel fails

Tags: html, vba, excel, parsing, selenium

I want to parse a list of local saved webpages. Sadly the webpages won't open with Internet Explorer (error is "page not responding"), but FireFox opens them just fine. So I had to find a "workaround" to get the souce code so that I can parse it for the information i want. Therefore I found SeleniumBasic.

I use Excel 2013 and SeleniumBasic 2.0.6.0


I encounter the following problem when using Selenium. This is a very short version of what the code should be:

```
Sub TestSeleniumParsing()

    Dim sel As Selenium.WebDriver
    Set sel = New Selenium.WebDriver
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim ihtml As IHTMLElement
    Dim ihtmlcoll As IHTMLElementCollection

    sel.Start "firefox", "about:blank"
    sel.Get "file:///D:/LocalWebPages/MV_999.htm" 'GET LOCAL WEBPAGE

    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = sel.PageSource
    Set sel = Nothing

    Set ihtmlcoll = html.getElementsByClassName("name") ' THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR 
                                                    WHICH USED TO WORK WHEN I USED 
                                                    InterExporerMedium INSTEAD OF Selenium
    For Each ihtml In ihtmlcoll
        'SOME CODE HERE BUT NOW NOT IMPORTANT...
    Next ihtml


    Set html = Nothing
    Set ihtml = Nothing
    Set ihtml = Nothing

End Sub
```

At the line `Set ihtmlcoll = html.getElementsByClassName("name")` I get an Error which I didn't receive before when I used Internet Explorer:
[image]

The reason why I don't want to write everything in Selenium VBA is because I already have the code in VBA.


Any help is much appreciated.


PS: this question is related to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458767/store-selenium-html-source-code-into-element-of-type-htmldocument/34459741?noredirect=1#comment56678625_34459741).

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to get the DOM with SeleniumBasic:

```
Sub Get_DOM_Late_Binding()
  Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
  driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

  Dim html: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
  html.Write driver.PageSource()

  Debug.Print html.body.innerText      
  driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub Get_DOM_Early_Binding()
  Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
  driver.Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

  Dim html As New HTMLDocument  ' Requires Microsoft HTML Library
  html.body.innerHTML = driver.ExecuteScript("return document.body.innerHTML;")
  ' CallByName html, "Write", VbMethod, driver.PageSource()

  Debug.Print html.body.innerText      
  driver.Quit
End Sub
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above examples:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Comment: You are such a gem, Florent B.. I'm lucky enough to come across your solution. I have got startled not to see this answer accepted.Thanks a lot.