# VBA - Selenium - Chrome - run-time Error -2146233078 (801315a)

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My VBA code stopped working last week after several months working fine.

In short, the error raises when executing driver.start

"Run-time Error '-2146233078 (801315a)':

The source was not found but some or all event logs could not be searched.
Inaccessible logs: Security."

```
Sub Go_Click()
Dim Driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set Driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
Driver.Start
Driver.Get "https://www.google.com"
Driver.Quit
End Sub
```

Does anyone had the same experience ?
Can it be solved ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Selenium: SeleniumBasic-2.0.9

Chrome Version
Versão 88.0.4324.190 (Compilação oficial) (64 bits)

Chromedriver version
88.0.4324.96

[image: Run-time error]

Answer (score 1):

in python we have to explicitly set the path for the cromedriver, and put it into the same folder as the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = "C:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/project/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
```

Can you confirm that your VBA Code has a source path to the chromedriver?

Comment: Hi, Patrick. Thank you for your time. My VBA code does not have a source path for the chomedriver. It has a reference to the selenium .tlb library. In addition the selenium path is in the environmental path. In addition, the same code in VBscript works fine.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to intiliaze the html document separately like in this comment by barrowc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458767/store-selenium-html-source-code-into-element-of-type-htmldocument   ------> look at the last answer in the link:                                         Dim sel As selenium.WebDriver
Set sel = New selenium.WebDriver
Dim html As HTMLDocument

sel.Start "firefox", "about:blank"
sel.Get "http://www.google.com/"

Set html = New HTMLDocument
html.body.innerHTML = sel.PageSource

Debug.Print html.body.innerText

Comment: I think you meant put Driver.Start "chrome", "about:blank" instead of only Driver.Start.
I get the same error ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem reported here (and elsewhere on the web) with the Run-time Error -2146233078 (801315a).

The problem occurs, I think, because SeleniumBasic forces its installation in the c:\users[username]\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic directory (there is no way to change this on installation so far as I can see), and on many systems, there is a group security policy in effect that restricts execution of .exe (and other executables) in the user's AppData directory (as a security precaution against malicious executables being installed in AppData).

This can be demonstrated by double clicking one of the web drivers (e.g., chromedriver.exe or edgedriver.exe) in the AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic directory. IF it is blocked, a system block window will appear, but if not, a command window opens indicating instantiation of the web driver. If you can instantiate a web driver this way, this solution is not, I think, for you.

Unless a user can remove the AppData execution restriction or white list the .exe files there (e.g., chromedriver.exe, edgedriver.exe, etc.) (which I could not do), the workaround--which I have now successfully accomplished--is to create a SeleniumBasic directory someplace other than under AppData (this might be in Program Files or Program Files (x86), but one will need administrative privileges to do that), copy the contents of the AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic directory to this new directory.

At this point, one can test that the new location permits .exe execution by the same test noted above demonstrating the execution restriction. Assuming the new SeleniumBasic directory is in a location from which execution of .exe files is permitted by the system, you are partway to the solution.

But only partway, because moving SeleniumBasic's files is not the end of the effort. On installation, SeleniumBasic registers itself and its components in multiple ways in the registry.

While one could do thin manually, using a tool such as NirSoft's RegScanner, one can find and export from the registry as a .reg file (the "original" file) all occurrences of the original path to the SeleniumBasic .dll, .tbl, and .exe files: c:\users[username]\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic, copy the original .reg file to a new file (the "revised" file), edit the revised file to change all occurrences of the noted path to the new path to SeleniumBasic, and save the revised file. (Note that keeping a .reg file with the original entries is prudent in case the prior set-up needs to be restored.)

Then import the revised .reg file to the registry and reboot.

Finally, in one's Office VBA projects using Selenium Basic, the Reference to the Selenium Type Library needs to be re-established.

That did it for me and now both the test .vbs scripts SeleniumBasis\Scripts and my VBA code previously attempting to make use of the Selenium Type Library work!

I hope this helps those who have been having this problem. SeleniumBasic is a useful tool for VBA coders to manipulate a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the idiotic error is easy to solve. When downloading the driver, read the name carefully. I was downloading the "chromedriver_mac64.zip" version because my brain was using shortcut and it read Chrome64.zip and it wasn't reading that it was the MAC version. I downloaded the version "chromedriver_win32.zip" and it was solved

Comment: Hello,
What you mention it is not definitly my case.
In fact I tested the same vba code about a month ago and all went fine.
I think this issue had to do with Microsoft updates.
My guess is that the execution of the chromedriver was blocked.

Comment: I'm using chromedriver in VBA Office 365/Win 10 without any problem. Try reinstalling office and testing a new project from 0. Alternatively you can use the old IE. I also use it without any problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the installation of Selenium Basic using "Run as administrator" it will be installed in program files